# How to create attachments in transit gateway module terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, terraform-modules

I have created a transit gateway using the terraform tgw module as shown below.

```html
module "transit-gateway" {
  source          = "terraform-aws-modules/transit-gateway/aws"
  version         = "1.4.0"
  name            = "tgw-nprod"
  description     = "My TGW shared with several other AWS accounts"
  amazon_side_asn = 64532

  enable_auto_accept_shared_attachments = true
  vpc_attachments = {
    vpc1 = {
      vpc_id                                          = module.vpc.vpc_id
      subnet_ids                                      = module.vpc.private_subnets
      dns_support                                     = true
      ipv6_support                                    = false
      transit_gateway_default_route_table_association = false
      transit_gateway_default_route_table_propagation = false
    }
  }

  ram_allow_external_principals = true
  ram_principals                = [1234567890, 0987654321]

  tags = {
    Purpose = "tgw-testing"
  }
}
```

I have created vpc using the terraform vpc module.

When I run the above terraform Iam getting error "**Error: error creating EC2 Transit Gateway VPC Attachment: DuplicateSubnetsInSameZone: Duplicate Subnets for same AZ**"

I have 2 private subnet in ap-south-1 and 1 public in ap-south-1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/tgw/tgw-getting-started.html#step-create-tgw) write that you can have your gateway in only one subnet per AZ:

> You must select at least one subnet. You can select **only one subnet per Availability Zone**.

Your error msg suggests that your `module.vpc.private_subnets` are in same AZ. You have to **redefine** your VPC so that `module.vpc.private_subnets` are in two different AZs, or just use **one subnet** in your `subnet_ids`.

To use one subnet:

```
subnet_ids                                      = [module.vpc.private_subnets[0]]
```

Comment: I tried to pass module.vpc.private_subnets[0] but in that case I am getting the error: "Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on .terraform/modules/transit-gateway/main.tf line 72, in resource "aws_ec2_transit_gateway_vpc_attachment" "this":
  72:   subnet_ids         = each.value["subnet_ids"]
    |----------------
    | each.value["subnet_ids"] is"

Comment: @SUBHASPATIL I updated the answer with what I believe should be done to use one subnet.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin, it worked. It was a silly mistake from my end.